# Is there a Monoid equivalent of Bifunctor?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, category-theory

When working with a [`Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html), we gain access to the `first` and `second` "map" functions. So basically it is a `Functor` that allows us to `fmap` in two different ways.

Is there something like this for `Monoid`? Some concept that allows us to append in two different ways?

For example, imagine an opaque `Matrix` type. It is not a list of lists or a vector of vectors, we have no clue how it is structured inside, but we know that we can append rows and columns to it.

Would there be some type class that allowed to do this?

```
class X a where
    firstAppend :: a -> a -> a
    secondAppend :: a -> a -> a

instance X Matrix where
    firstAppend = appendRow
    secondAppend = appendColumn
```

Comment: I'm not aware of anything standard defined. You could certainly define it yourself. I'm not sure of the value since at the type level there's nothing to differentiate. I think a more appropriate solution might be `newtype` wrapper(s) and two different instances, similar to `Product` and `Sum` in `Data.Monoid`.

Comment: Yeah @ryachza I think that could be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: This is regularly done in an ad-hoc manner, e.g. [in diagrams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.4.1.2/docs/Diagrams-TwoD-Combinators.html#v:-61--61--61-), [matrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html#g:9) or [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.18.1.0/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-Data.html#g:12).

Comment: Depending on your exact requirements, you might look into [semirings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring), which are basically algebraic structures with both "addition" and "multiplication" operations. (Your `appendRow`/`appendColumn` is not an example of a semiring, but (square) matrices do form a semiring under matrix addition and matrix multiplication.)

Comment: You might also consider looking into bimodules.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could do something like this with indexed Monoids:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies   #-}

module IndexedMonoids where

class MonoidIx (m :: k -> *) where
  type Null m :: k
  type Mult m (i :: k) (j :: k) :: k

  nullIx :: m (Null m)
  multIx :: m i -> m j -> m (Mult m i j)

class MonoidIx2 (m :: k -> l -> *) where
  type Null1 m :: k
  type Null2 m :: l
  type Mult1 m (i :: k) (j :: k) :: k
  type Mult2 m (p :: l) (q :: l) :: l

  null1Ix :: m (Null1 m) p
  null2Ix :: m i (Null2 m)
  mult1Ix :: m i p -> m j p -> m (Mult1 m i j) p
  mult2Ix :: m i p -> m i q -> m i (Mult2 m p q)
```

You'd expect a bunch of laws (identity, associativity, commutativity when you put 4 blocks together). A trivial example of an indexed Monoid: the one where the index does not matter:

```
newtype Dummy (m :: *) (i :: k) = Dummy { getDummy :: m }

instance Monoid m => MonoidIx (Dummy m :: * -> *) where
  type Null (Dummy m)     = ()
  type Mult (Dummy m) i j = ()

  nullIx = Dummy mempty
  multIx (Dummy i) (Dummy j) = Dummy $ mappend i j
```

I'll let you implement the instance for matrices ;)

Comment: Really love this solution! But actually I think that this is overkill for the problem I'm facing. Thank you very much :)